# Orchard CMS Enumeration Field values in migrations

Tags: .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

In Orchard CMS I am creating a content part Vehicle with enumeration field:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(typeof(VehiclePart).Name, part => part
            .Attachable()
            .WithField("InsuranceType", field => field.OfType("EnumerationField")));
```

Now that I have EnumerationField, I need to set values for it. Any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.WithField("InsuranceType", field =>
    field.OfType("EnumerationField")
        .WithSetting("EnumerationFieldSettings.Options",
            string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine,
                new[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"}))
```

should do the trick, I think. Enumeration options are settings, stored as a newline-separated list.

Comment: What if those foo, bar and baz should load from a database table? Or they are titles of one other content-type?

Comment: Then it's not the enumeration field that you need. You'll have to build your own.